# Implement left outer join using EF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to convert sql statement to EF using c# in VS2015

below is SQL statement:

```
Select i.cdin_cdindexid,p.pinv_PerformaInvID,coalesce(i.cdin_serial,0) as depno 
                         ,coalesce(convert(datetime,left(convert(nvarchar,i.cdin_startunstufdate,120),10),120),'-') as deidate,coalesce(i.cdin_goodsDesc,'-') as gooddesc ,coalesce(i.cdin_Customdeclar,'-') as custdec 
                         ,coalesce(i.cdin_NoofPackages,0) as pkg,coalesce(i.cdin_WT,0) as wt ,coalesce(i.cdin_volumewt,0) as vwt ,coalesce(i.cdin_MortgageAmount,0) as lcamt,coalesce(p.pinv_name,'-') as invno,coalesce(p.pinv_TotalAmount,0) as invamt,p.pinv_Status,p.pinv_InvoiceProperty as prop 
                         ,coalesce(c.comp_name,'-') as custname,coalesce(Comp_CompanyId,'-') as custid ,coalesce(c.comp_idcust,'-') as accpacno,coalesce(t.Terr_Caption,'-') as Terr,convert(nvarchar,'01',2) as type     
                         from cdindex i inner join   company c on i.cdin_CompanyId =c.Comp_CompanyId  inner join Territories t on i.cdin_Secterr =t.Terr_TerritoryID left outer join PerformaInv p on i.cdin_cdindexid=p.pinv_CDIndexId 
                         where(cdin_deleted Is null And c.comp_deleted Is null And t.Terr_Deleted Is null And p.pinv_deleted Is null)
                         and cdin_startunstufdate between '2016-06-01' and '2016-07-28'
                          and (p.pinv_status in('Draft','Posted') or pinv_status is null) and (p.pinv_InvoiceProperty ='01' or p.pinv_InvoiceProperty is null )
```

I tried to implement the joins but i'm stuck in how to left outer join using into and DefaultIfEmpty() on PerformaInv table then `on i.cdin_cdindexid=p.pinv_CDIndexId`

This what i tried to:

```
ar q = (from i in db.CDIndexes
             join c in db.Companies on i.cdin_CompanyId equals c.Comp_CompanyId
             join t in db.Territories on i.cdin_Secterr equals t.Terr_TerritoryID into
              p from pr in p.DefaultIfEmpty

             where (i.cdin_startunstufdate>= new DateTime(2016 - 06 - 01) && i.cdin_startunstufdate>= new DateTime(2016-06-28)

             )



             select new
             {

                 i.cdin_CDIndexID,
                 i.cdin_Serial,
                 i.cdin_startunstufdate,
                 i.cdin_goodsDesc,
                 i.cdin_Customdeclar,
                 i.cdin_NoofPackages,
                 i.cdin_WT,
                 i.cdin_volumewt,
                 i.cdin_MortgageAmount,

             });
```

I know that there is a lot of things missing but i really get sucked.

Comment: First make it using inner join, then turning it into left outer join is a matter of adding a single line. Also if you create navigation properties in your model, you'll not need to write joins at all.

Comment: @IvanStoev This is what do :`from i in db.CDIndexes
                 join c in db.Companies on i.cdin_CompanyId equals c.Comp_CompanyId
                 join t in db.Territories on i.cdin_Secterr equals t.Terr_TerritoryID 
                 join p in db.PerformaInvs on i.cdin_CDIndexID equals p.pinv_CDIndexId`

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry Mr.Ivan how could i do navigation? like in this [link](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/) , please could you explain the way to implement the code without using joins.

Comment: Yes, like in that link. It's hard to be explained w/o having the "entity" classes, but the idea is that if you have two classes A and B and one-to-many relation, you put in A `public ICollection<B> Bs P { get; set; }` and in B `public A A { get; set; }` and then inside the queries you can use either `a.Bs` or `b.A` and EF will join A and B tables for you.

Comment: @IvanStoev Unfortunately i didn't understand what you are saying, mmm i guss that using ORM with ordinary SQL satements is the best solution with Joins or with complex SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, it's better to use navigation properties. But once you started with manual joins, turning inner join to left outer join (although not natural) is not so hard.

So given your joins

```
from i in db.CDIndexes
join c in db.Companies on i.cdin_CompanyId equals c.Comp_CompanyId
join t in db.Territories on i.cdin_Secterr equals t.Terr_TerritoryID
join p in db.PerformaInvs on i.cdin_CDIndexID equals p.pinv_CDIndexId
...
```

you turn any of those to left outer join by using the pattern shown in [join clause (C# Reference) - Left Outer Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_2)

```
from i in db.CDIndexes
join c in db.Companies on i.cdin_CompanyId equals c.Comp_CompanyId
join t in db.Territories on i.cdin_Secterr equals t.Terr_TerritoryID
join p in db.PerformaInvs on i.cdin_CDIndexID equals p.pinv_CDIndexId
// the following line turns the above join to left outer
into p_Join from p in p_Join.DefaultIfEmpty()
...
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much i want to test it against the original SQL statement, but i have one more question , please how could i implement the (Is Null) in where clause to complete this where in LINQ:   `  where (i.cdin_startunstufdate >= new DateTime(2016 - 06 - 01) && i.cdin_startunstufdate >= new DateTime(2016 - 06 - 28)
                    && p.pinv_Status == "Draft" || p.pinv_Status == "Posted" && p.pinv_InvoiceProperty == "01"

                 )
`

Comment: SQL `Is Null` => LINQ `== null`

Comment: I tried implement it since 2 hours but the result is the query generated is different from the one in SQL server.

Comment: You know the SO rules. Only one question per post and no "updates" / "additional" questions once it's get answered. I think  the above is covering the *Implement left outer join using EF* question, if you have other requirements, please post another question. For this one, you may accept the answer, post your own answer or delete the post (let me know if you want to do the last, so I delete the answer in order to allow you to do that).